# How do I merge two images into one?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, d3.js

What I am doing is converting a chart (HTML for chart legend + SVG for chart body) generated by D3.js into a image, right now I am using both html2canvas and manually convert SVG into image data, the reason is because the html2canvas can only handle the html part and text element inside the SVG.

**So my question is:**

Once I have **both images data** (the svg part is like: `'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+ btoa(svg);` (I can turn it into similar data-url by building image object and draw it on canvas ) and html part is from `canvas.toDataURL` ), how can I **merge** them together to get **the full image**

```
///////////////               ///////////////           ///////////////
/             /               ///////////////           /             /
/             /               ///////////////           /             /
/             /      +        ///////////////   =       /             /
///////////////               ///////////////           ///////////////
///////////////               /             /           /             /
///////////////               ///////////////           ///////////////
```

I guess canvas may have the ability( overlay mode ) to merge multi-layers, but I can not figure out how to do that. So any code sample is appreciated.

Comment: SVG is a vector format, what exactly do you consider a merge? Plopping one image on top of the other?

Comment: @user2867288 Basically Yes. Like I said I got two image, one has chart body part while another has legend part, I want to put them together to get a image has both chart and legend. Currently problems about canvas are: [1] I do not know to overlap layers(like Photoshop layers) [2] These two images could have some same part(like the chart axis)  but not in same place( 10px diff when compare them, this sounds ridiculous, but when it is true.) I need to remove that part in the bottom layer and only use top layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what can you do is to write the image sources into the canvas, then use the canvas composite operation. This way you can overlay the two image using the method which fits best to your needs.

Here are some samples using the `globalCompositeOperation`

http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2014/02/24/using-blend-modes-in-html-canvas/

Comment: thanks, I was reading that post when you post reply. It is a little hard for me to understand.

Comment: Link is dead :-(